# Excel 2010 generate tables from power query connected tables

Tags: excel, excel-2010, powerquery

I am using excel 2010 (not by choice) and I have a master data table from power query (has all outputs sorted and arranged)

I know that there are limitations using vba with excel 2010's power query.

What I am trying for is for each sheet to be be named after a value in a list of filters (which is dynamic) and for each of those sheet's to have a table with all of the values that meet that filter criteria.

## Tables

#### Filters Table

| Filters |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

#### Output_Query

| ID | Filter | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | xxx |
| 2 | 1 | yyy |
| 3 | 2 | zzz |
| 4 | 1 | ddd |
| 5 | 2 | eee |
| 6 | 2 | fff |

## Code

#### VBA

```
Private Sub generate_Pages()
    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count - 1
        If (ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name <> "Data") Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Delete
        End If
    Next
    Dim sta(0 To 1) As Integer
    sta(0) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    sta(1) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").ListObjects("Filters").DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add before:=Sheets(sta(0)), Count:=sta(1), Type:=xlWorksheet
    Dim ctr As Integer
    ctr = 1
    Dim tmp As Worksheet
    Dim tmplo As ListObject
    For Each itm In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").ListObjects("Filters").DataBodyRange
        Set tmp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ctr)
        With tmp
            .Name = itm.Value
            Set tmplo = tmp.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcQuery, "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Output_Query", , xlYes, tmp.Range("A1"))
            tmplo.Name = "Output_Query_" & tmp.Name
            tmplo.QueryTable.Connection = "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Output_Query"
            tmplo.QueryTable.Destination = tmp.Range("a1")
            tmplo.QueryTable.CommandType = xlCmdDefault
            tmplo.QueryTable.CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [" & Output_Query & "] where [Filter] =""" & itm.Name & """")
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

The line that causes the error is `tmplo.QueryTable.CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [" & Output_Query & "] where [Filter] =""" & itm.Name & """")`

Comment: where are you defining Output_Query that you are using as a variable?

Comment: @horseyride i edited the question fix the name of the output from **data table** to **output_query**